# Moving my site from my own computer to my online server I get an undefined class error? [Fat Free Framework]

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

```
Internal Server Error

Undefined class DB

#0 /home/static2/public_html/casualtee/Casualtee12/lib/base.php:1684 F3::error(500,'Undefined class DB')
```

I set permissions to 777 to make sure that wasn't an issue. The base.php, db.php and index.php files are included where they should be on the server... It's PHP 5.3.8 on my online server, and 5.3.6 on my local computer.

Where can I even start to diagnose this problem?

Comment: can you create a test.php file that includes the db class and simply instantiates a new db class object ($bla = new $db).... do you error out even after instantiating the class?

Comment: What is there in line 1684 of base.php?

Comment: I fixed it by re-uploading all of my files, I guess something was corrupt in the transfer. Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a (late) answer to this. I had the same problem and it was fixed by editing some files (including the index.php and db.php file).

Simply the act of inserting debug code into the framework, and then running it was enough to fix it. Then remove the debug code (or in my case, I checked out from git) and it continued to work.